# Particular integral of partial differential equation $(D^2 +3DD'+2D'^2)z = x + y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Particular integral of the following PDE is coming out to be different if I apply different rules:
$$(D^2 +3DD'+2D'^2)z = x+y$$

where $D = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $D' = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$

**Method 1:**
$$F(D,D')z = f(ax+by)$$
here $F(a,b) \neq  0$, so $P.I. = \frac{(x+y)^3}{6}$

**Method 2:**
By taking $$ 2D'^2 $$ common in the denominator, and expanding the denominator in form of $$ (1 + p)^{-1}. $$ I am getting $$ \frac{xy^2}{4} - \frac{y^3}{24}. $$

**Method 3**
Similarly by taking $D^2$ common, I am getting a different value.

Can the above methods be applied to this PDE ? If yes, then why is the answer different for different methods?

Comment: Do $D,D'$ mean $\partial_x,\partial_y$?

Comment: Yes. I used these notations as they are commonly used.

Comment: Well, there are many notations for derivatives, so I think you should still clarify in the question.

Comment: You can factor $D^2+3DD'+2D'^2=(D+D')(D+2D')$. Then the homogeneous or complementary solution is $f(y-x)+g(y-2x)$. You can modify any particular solution by some homogeneous solution to get another solution, the space of particular solutions is indeed the full solution space. --- But check the trials you got, I see not how inserting into the PDE gives the same terms on both sides.